# Suppose that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }c_n{x^{n}}$ for all $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }c_n{x^{n}}$ for all $x.$

Show that if $f$ is an odd function, $c_{0}=c_{2}=\dots=0$

and if $f$ is an even function, $c_{1}=c_{3}=\dots=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F$ is said to be even if $F(x) =F(-x)$ and odd if $F(x)=-F(-x)$.

Now use these to get your answer

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using the definition of even and odd functions you have to know that if a power series vanishes then all the coefficients vanish. This requires repeated differentiation of the series. Any book on Complex Analysis will have a proof of the fact that a power series can be differentiated term by term any number of times.